# turbo c graphics no error but doesn't run

Tags: c, bgi, turbo-c

The following code doesn't have any error but it won't run. There's just a flash on the screen when I run it. It doesn't provide any output. what do I have to do?

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph (&gd, &gm, "");
    setbkcolor (15);
    setcolor (0);
    settextjustify (1,1);
    settextstyle (3,0,12);
    outtextxy (getmaxx()/2, 1, "BATAAN PENINSULA STATE UNIVERSITY");
    outtextxy(getmaxx()/2, 3, "MAIN CAMPUS");
    settextstyle (3,0,10);
    outtextxy (getmaxx()/2, 5, "College of Engineering and Architecture");
    outtextxy (getmaxx()/2, 7, "Bachelor of Science in Civil Engineering(BSCE)");
    settextstyle (3,0,15);
    outtextxy (getmaxx()/2, getmaxy()/2, "COMPUTERIZED TUTORIAL SYSTEM");
    outtextxy (getmaxx()/2, 30, "(CORRECTION IN TAPING)");
    settextstyle (3,0,10);
    outtextxy (getmaxx()/2, getmaxy(), "Programmed by: BSCE-3A Group 8");

    getch();
    closegraph();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In initgrapgh, your "" are empty. They should have the path to the bgi library.
It should look something like this:

```
initgraph(&gd, &gm, "C:\\TC\\BGI");
```